# Django Admin Page: Blank View

Tags: python, django, admin

I've been trying to get Django working completely but I'm having issues with my admin page. It is only a blank view; no login, no title, no error... 
After setting up, I have run:

```
 python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate
```

Here is settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'books.apps.BooksConfig',
]
```

Here is urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from books.views import hello, my_homepage_view, current_datetime, hours_ahead

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^hello/$', hello),
# url(r'^$', my_homepage_view),
url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
url(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead)
]
```

Like I said, there is not a 404 or any type of error page when localhost:8000/admin/ is accessed, it is just a blank, white page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error would show up in your traceback. You can post it here.

Comment: Are other pages working correctly ?

Comment: try manage.py collectstatic

Comment: If you are in debug mode, the stack trace should print to the screen.

Comment: check your MEDIA global var in settings.py or use collectstatic command line tool to get all static assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was commented by a few people in the comments above.

My problem was solved by running:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by reinstalling Django in my virtual env.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, could you also provide the steps used by you to achieve this, it would help users of the site  to quickly solve the same problem if they face it :)

Comment: Thank you, that works but I don't know what was the problem :|

Answer (score 0):

So dumb, it's been a long night. I found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525977/the-django-admin-page-is-not-opening-where-am-i-going-wrong).
What worked for me was adding the trailing slash after the endpoint.

`localhost:8000/admin/` instead of `localhost:8000/admin`