# The Django admin page is not opening. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, django, admin

I've just started working with Django 3.0.1. I used the `python manage.py runserver` command and tried opening `localhost:8000/admin` page but I get hit with a `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3731` in the command prompt and the server stops running.
This is the urls configuration for the basic page I have been working on.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  #navigation url for admin page
    path('', include('blog.urls')), 
]
```

Is there any error which I have to rectify?

Comment: You missed the `include()`.

Comment: Add your settings.py code, to debug your issue efficiently!

Comment: I was facing the same problem and got the solution, actually 3.0 versions of Django is having some compatibility issues with python 3.7. You can either downgrade Django to 2.x.x versions or you can upgrade Python to 3.8 version. Choice is yours. Read more at link.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230667/django-server-stops-immediatly-after-login-into-admin-page][1]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and what worked for me was I used localhost:8000/admin/ instead of localhost:8000/admin